# What does Apple think about complete Web Based Apps?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I used to be a Web Developer and I'm not experienced at developing iOS Apps.
I've just found out that I can make the whole App a Mobile Website. So my question is if Apple accept these kind of Apps, where the whole content is a normal mobile friendly Website. As Apple can't control the content displayed in such an App.

Comment: If you look at ionic framework. All the content is written in html and js.

Comment: Clause 2.12 of the app review guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ covers this. @SimonSchüpbach, you can develop stand-alone apps in html and js but you can't simply use a web view to display your existing website. Also the app needs to have some functionality beyond simple display of information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways you can leverage your expertise as a web developer to develop iOS apps:

- Use `SFWebView` or `WKWebView` and use it to present HTML (either stored or retrieved remotely) to the user. In this case your app would have to go through AppStore review. There's plenty of apps like these, so I would assume it would not be a huge issue.
- Use a framework like React Native that compiles Javascript dialects into native UIKit. Again, the app would be up for review in the AppStore. It would feel more iOS-like to the users.
- Develop a bona-fide web app that looks great on any phone and you skip the AppStore part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working as a web developer too and we did a few iOS apps for our clients. Basically 90% or more where pure web view and so far we didn't had problems getting through with them.